# Segmentation fault when adding while loop

Tags: c

This code was working fine before I added the while loop; it's supposed to take in 4 letters, then output number of correct letter and position, and number of correct letter only. But when I added the while loop (commented in the code now), I got segmentation fault when compiling. It seems that the line giving the problem is line 33, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work only when I add the while loop.

```
  8 #include "cs1010.h"
  9 
 10 long set_identical(long identical[4], char input[4], char guess[4])
 11 { 
 12   for (long i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
 13     if (input[i] == guess[i]){
 14       identical[i] += 1;
 15     }
 16   }
 17   return *identical;
 18 }
 19 
 20 long sum(long identical[4])
 21 { 
 22   long sum = 0; 
 23   for (long i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
 24     sum += identical[i];
 25   }
 26   return sum;
 27 }
 28 
 29 char change_array(char x[], long swap[])
 30 { 
 31   for (long i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
 32     if (swap[i] == 1){
 33       x[i] = '0';
 34     }
 35   }
 36   return *x;
 37 }
 38 
 39 long set_color(long color, char guess[], char input[],
 40     long swap1[], long swap2[])
 41 {
 42   *input = change_array(input, swap1);
 43   *guess = change_array(guess, swap2);
 44   for(long i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
 45     for (long j = 0; j < 4; j += 1){
 46       if (input[i] != '0' && input[i] == guess[j]){
 47         color += 1;
 48         swap1[i] = 1;
 49         swap2[j] = 1;
 50         *input = change_array(input, swap1);
 51         *guess = change_array(guess, swap2);
 52       }
 53     }
 54   }
 55   return color;
 56 }
 57 
 58 int main()
 59 {
 60   char* input = cs1010_read_word();
 61   long position = 0;
 62 
 63 
 64   //while(position != 4){
 65     char* guess = cs1010_read_word();
 66     long color = 0;
 67     long identical[4] = {0};
 68     long identical2[4] = {0};
 69     *identical = set_identical(identical, input, guess);
 70     position = sum(identical)   
 71     for (long i = 0; i < 4; i += 1){
 72       identical2[i] = identical[i];
 73     }
 74 
 75     color = set_color(color, guess, input, identical, identical2);
 76 
 77     cs1010_print_long(position);
 78     cs1010_print_string(" ");
 79     cs1010_println_long(color);
 80   //}
 81 }
```

Comment: Please replace your pointer notation you use with arrays to arrays notation. It will clarify your intentions to us and to yourself. As for now these are not clear to me.

Comment: Why are you returning the first element of `x` in `change_array`, and why, upon returning that element, are you storing it in the first element of the array that you passed into that function (essentially doing `input[0] = input[0]`)?

Comment: @Shannon I'd suggest you give a try to a  debugger (like GDB) which is a good way to fix segfaults.

Comment: When posting code your question refers to by line number (debuggers breaks at line 33, compiler complains about line 50, etc), please do NOT post the code list with line numbers from your editor. Rather, mark the line references with inlines comments, `// <<== line 33 here`. Otherwise, it is impossible to copy/paste/run your code without editing each line to remove the superfluous line numbers, and believe me, *no one* enjoys that unnecessary task.

Comment: ...however it is obvious that lines 1 to 7 are missing!

Comment: @WeatherVane best guess, it contains a comment header with the student name, class, etc.

Comment: ... and more `#include` statements.

Comment: You really shouldn't post your code to the assignment in full like this. Why not ask on Piazza (private note to instructors)? Context: I happen to be helping out with this school module, and it uses a custom library called cs1010 (which is the module code)

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @WeatherVane judging buy all the crap pulled in by [`cs1010.h`](https://github.com/nus-cs1010-1819-s1/libcs1010/blob/master/include/cs1010.h), no other includes are required. You have to love those "helpful" libraries that black-box the very tasks someone should learn as part of the beginning curricula  rather than being fed from a trough of mystery.